# Not able to inject logger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

**app.admin.routes.js**

```
(function () {
        'use strict';
    
    angular
        .module('app.admin')
        .run(appRun);

    appRun.$inject = ['routeHelper', 'app.core.services.notificationService'];

    function appRun(routeHelper, notificationService) {
        debugger;
        routeHelper.configureRoutes(getRoutes());

        function getRoutes() {
            return [
                {
                    state: 'admin',
                    url: '/admin',
                    templateUrl: 'app/features/admin/admin.html',
                    controller: 'Admin as vm',
                    resolve: {
//                        signalRConnection: function() {
//                            return notificationService.onReady;
//                        }
                    }, 
                    settings: {
                        navigation: {
                            group: "application",
                            label: "Admin",
                            //label: "navigation.admin",
                            icon: "fa-lock",
                            order: 2
                        }
                        //content: '<i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Admin'
                    }
                }
            ];
        }
    }
})();
```

**admin.js**

```
(function () {
        'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.admin')
        .controller('Admin', Admin);

    Admin.$inject = ['logger'];

    function Admin(logger) {
        /*jshint validthis: true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'Admin';
        
        activate();

        function activate() {
            logger.info('Activated Admin View');
        }
    }
})();
```

**adminctrlSpec.js**

> describe("AdminController", function () {
>
> ```
> var _logger;
>
> beforeEach(function() {
>     module("app.admin", function ($provide) {          
>         $provide.value('routeHelper', {
>             configureRoutes: function(routes) {
>             }
>         });
>         $provide.value('app.core.services.notificationService', {
>             signalRConnection: function () {
>             }
>         });
>     });
> });
>
> beforeEach(function () {
>     inject([
>         'logger', function (logger) {
>             debugger;
>         }
>     ]);
> });
>
> it("asd", function()  {
>     debugger;
>
> });
> ```
>
> });

I am able to use logger in all of my other Specs. But unable to inject for admin.js.

```
beforeEach(function () {
>         inject([
>             'logger', function (logger) {
>                 debugger;
>             }
>         ]);
>     });

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: loggerProvider <- logger
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [    
        'app.admin',
        'app.modelling',
        'app.layout'
    ]);

})();
```

Problem solved .i forgot to add  `beforeEach(function () { module("app"); });`